# I have a questions regarding matlab figures. I use bar3 function in matlab and want to adjust my axes

Tags: matlab

I have a 2d matrix called myval. Its size is 21x11.

What I  want to do is plot only the first 11 rows and all columns i.e 11x11. So I use a bar3 function in matlab to do this which gives me a good plot.

Now the z axis is the actual value stored in `myval` matrix. But it so happens that I want the x and y axis values (which represent the corresponding row and column) to start at 0 instead. That is value of (1,1) will be (0,0) and value at (1,2) will be (0,1). I do not want to change the actual value in the `myval` matrix. I just want to shift the axis. 
this is my actual code

```
     bar3(myval(1:t,:));
     xlim([0 p]); 
     ylim([0 t]);
     zlim([0 1); 
     set(gca,'fontsize',16); 
     set(gca,'XTick',(0:2:p)); 
     set(gca,'YTick',0:2:t); 
     set(gca,'ZTick',0:1);
```

Comment: The way this question is worded, it is not clear at all what you want

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `bar3` both an x and Y input then the columns will appear where you want them.

```
x = 0:10;
Y = myval(1:t,:);
bar3(x,Y)
```

Or, to controll both the x and y axis, you can use:

```
x = 0:10;
bar3(Y)
set(gca,'YTickLabel', x)
set(gca,'XTickLabel', x)
```

Comment: I tried doing that. Let me actual make it more precise what I want. At location 1 on x and y axis, I want value 0 and so on. I can go to the axis properties and do it manually. but it much tedious when I need to use this very frequently.

Comment: I figured out that tick is used to set the tick locations on a graph while ticklabel is used to label the specific ticks out of those ticked locations.

Comment: @Molly the question is how do you give actual x/y values to the plot, not just change their labels. Just changing labels isn't enough, for instance if you want to add more points to the plot using scatter3 or something.